# Why I got this error Cannot find module 'nestjs/common' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

I am creating a controller in nest js
this is file auth.controller.ts

```
import { Controller } from 'nestjs/common';
@Controller()
export class AppController {}
```

Why I get this error?
error TS2307: Cannot find module 'nestjs/common' or its corresponding type declarations.

I installed all dependencies, deleted the dist folder, and rerun yarn start:dev.

Here is all my dependencies.

[Here is all my dependencies.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iODs8.png)

Answer (score 3):

The package is called [`@nestjs/common`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nestjs/common), not `nestjs/common`

Then:

```
import { Controller } from '@nestjs/common';
```

tip: read the docs carefully https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers

Answer (score 3):

If you corrected the typo but you are still getting the error

`cannot find module '@nestjs/common' or its corresponding type declarations.`

Then you may need to install

```
npm install @nestjs/common
npm install @nestjs/core
```

It worked for me.

Comment: I installed these packages, but I encountered a problem after installing them. When I removed the import and wrote it again from scratch, it worked for me.